# Best way to authenticate to MongoDB with pyramid

Tags: mongodb, authentication, pyramid

I am running a pyramid server that need to access mongo with authentication. Both servers (DB and Pyramid) are running in the same machine. As per [pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/database/mongodb.html)/[pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/authentication.html) documentation, I can use a URI like,

```
uri = "mongodb://user:password@example.com/the_database"
```

and authenticate. However, this seems very unsecure since anyone who somehow gets access to the pyramid code then see the plain password (even if it's a hash) associated with the server user.

**What is the best way to mitigate this problem?**

I was thinking to prompt the user who start the server for the password for Mongo. Is that a good idea? has anyone done something like that in pyramid?

Or should I store password in a secure location in the server where only pyramid server has read access?

What is the preferred way? what if I want to access the mongo server from another computer? which method is better in that case?

How have you guys configured it? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: A common pattern, used also on Heroku, is using an environment variable (import os; uri = os.environ('MONGODSN')). Of course the user running pyramid should be secure.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what it does. can you explain/point me somewhere? thank you :)

Comment: os.environ expose as a Python dict the guest's OS environment variables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). So your script could just suppose someone have put in a environment variable your access string and you it.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of solving this if you're running any software on a multi user server is to make sure the server software is running on a separate user account, store the URI in an INI file and make sure the INI file is only readable by that user account. This ensures that only the server software user account (and any admin accounts) can see the URI string.